# Debezium Mysql Connector Failed with IllegalStateException for history topic with infinite retention

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka-connect, cdc, debezium

We have a Debezium MySQL connector running where the history topic already has infinite retention. But weirdly the connector fails all of a sudden with the following exception

```
"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The database history couldn't be recovered. 
Consider to increase the value for database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms
```

One other thing I could notice was there was a huge amount of messages being inserted into the history topic due to creation and deletion of the temp tables(not being followed by the debezium connector) in the database being monitored. Can these messages be the reason for the connector failing to read the history topic messages? We thought of enabling log compaction for the history topic but noticed a couple of issues recommending not to enable the same. https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-239.

Dropping the history topic and restarting the connector in `schema_recovery` mode restarted the connector fine, but want to know what measures can be taken to avoid these types of outages. Is there any option that allows only storing the DDL messages for the tables being monitored.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is now an option depending on what version of Debezium you are on, [database.history.store.only.captured.tables.ddl](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-database-history-store-only-captured-tables-ddl).

I haven't tried this myself, but I was looking for a similar thing. The documentation states the following;

> A Boolean value that specifies whether the connector should record all DDL statements
> true records only those DDL statements that are relevant to tables whose changes are being captured by Debezium. Set to true with care because missing data might become necessary if you change which tables have their changes captured.
> The safe default is false.

I 'guess' if you control the tables you are monitoring in a strict manner in your connector, it would be safe to set this to true.

On another note, for recovery, you might want to try and up the value for 'database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms' (default is 100ms).

Good luck!